# Gedoley Israel's views on the army service in Israel

Tags: rabbis, army-military-war

There are many Haredim who refuse to join the Army.

What are the opinions of Contemporary Gedolei Israel on Bachurei Yeshivot to join the Israeli army?

Comment: Haredi gedolei Israel are mostly against it, dati leumi gedolei Israel are mostly for it. Not sure this is a question about judaism though.

Comment: Why is this flagged as off-topic? It’s clearly asking about a contemporary halachic issue discussed in the poskim.